# Can't catch HTTP error code using an Interceptor

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

I'm trying to use an Interceptor to catch all 401 errors and kick the user from the session, but I've been able to catch it only by checking every query

This works:

**Service:**

```
const httpOptions: { headers; observe; } = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    observe: 'response'
};

createSomething(something: Something): Observable<HttpEvent<Something>> {

    return this.http.post<Something>(this.urlSomething, something, httpOptions)
}
```

---

**Component**:

```
this.somethingService.createSomething(incomingSomething).subscribe(
    res => {
        result = res;

        if (result.status == 401) {

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.authenticationService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }, 1000);

        return;
    }
);
```

---

But if I try to use an Interceptor it doesn't catch the error, what could be the issue?

**Interceptor:**

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {

            if (err.status === 401) {

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.authenticationService.logout();
                    location.reload(true);
                }, 1000);
            }

            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

---

Comment: A non-2xx status code isn't actually an *error*.

Comment: Oh, so there's no workaround? I guess I should do a few modifications in the backend

Comment: What do you mean *"no workaround"*? It just means you can't catch it with `catchError`, you can still process it with other stream operators.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is considered as an error by HttpClient. I expect the first one not to work since it uses the success callback to test for a 401 response. And I expect the second one to work fine. I use such an interceptor myself in all my projects. What happens when you add a tap() to your interceptor? Is it registered as an interceptor correctly? I find it odd that you named it JwtInterceptor although it has nothing to do with JWT. Cound this be related to your issue?

Comment: @JBNizet I guess I'm thinking of fetch or axios. In that case I agree with you, the first snippet shouldn't work and the second should be fine.

Comment: If the first one actually works, maybe you have another interceptor that transforms errors into successes.

Comment: I don't have any. It was called JWT because it used to work with a function related to the JWT token. I'm just able to catch the status code

Comment: My guess is that your interceptor is not properly registered then. Or that it's registered in one module and not in the one where you're testing it. Here's a stackblitz showing that it works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5kitrb